# Passing named parameters from one powershell script to another

Tags: powershell

I have a situation in which I have script_1.ps1 that gets called directly by a user. Script_1.ps1 is really just an entry point (at minimum providing just a hard coded config value) to script_2.ps1, which contains shared, factored out logic. I want the user to be able to pass any or all required arguments to script_1, which in turn must pass to script_2. If not all the required parameters are passed by the user, there's logic in script_2 that will prompt the user for the information.

In my ideal setup, I'd have script_1 accept named parameters from the user, and then script_2 accept the named parameters from script_1. For example, my script_1.ps1 would look something like this:

```
param (
    [switch] $Help = $false,
    [switch] $Quiet,
    [string] $Param1,
    [string] $Param2,
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] $args
)

if (!$Help) {
    .\script_2.ps1 -ServiceName "Service name here" #also pass any other args that were set by user (may be none, several, or all)
}
```

Then my script_2.ps1 would look something like this:

```
param (    
    [switch] $Quiet,
    [Alias("l")]
    [string] $ServiceName,
    [string] $Param1,
    [string] $Param2,
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] $args
)

# do things with arguments here
```

Is it possible to achieve this without enumerating all arguments when I call script_2.ps1 from script_1.ps1? My script_1 has about 20 different possible parameters, so something like this would get messy pretty fast:

```
.\script_2.ps1 -ServiceName "Service name here" -Quiet $Quiet -Param1 $Param1 -Param2 $Param2
```

The closest I've gotten to making this work is with the following, but then it cuts off arguments with spaces by the time they get to script_2. Putting escaped quotes around $args results in no arguments getting passed.

```
param (
    [switch] $Help = $false,
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] $args
)

if (!$Help) {
    Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file `".\script_2.ps1`" -ServiceName `"Service name here`" $args"
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing a trick to do this as a relative newcomer to powershell... TIA for any help!

Comment: You can have the first script output an custom object with properties that match some of your second script parameter names. Then in the second script, use the `valuefrompipelinebypropertyname` parameter attribute.

Comment: [1] the `$args` variable is an automatic $Var. you ought not to use it as a parameter name. [2] have you looked at `$PSBoundParamters` yet?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey $PSBoundParameters is exactly what I was after! Really surprised that didn't come up when I was googling around this problem. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @allison - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) to pass the collection of parameters from the first script into the second script. All this means is that instead of writing out the parameters to script2.ps1 longhand, you pass in a hashtable of key-value pairs.

Fortunately, there's a built-in hashtable which already contains the parameters passed in to a script or a function - `$PSBoundParameters` - so you can just splat that straight down from `script1.ps1` into `script2.ps1`...

Note that you invoke a "splat" with the `@` symbol, not `$` - i.e. `@PSBoundParameters` in this case.

**script.ps1**

```bsh
param (
    [switch] $Help = $false,
    [switch] $Quiet,
    [string] $Param1,
    [string] $Param2,
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] $args
)

if (!$Help) {
    write-host "script1.ps1"
    write-host ($PSBoundParameters | ft | out-string);
    . .\script2.ps1 @PSBoundParameters
}
```

**script2.ps1**

```bsh
param (    
    [switch] $Quiet,
    [Alias("l")]
    [string] $ServiceName,
    [string] $Param1,
    [string] $Param2,
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] $args
)

# do things with arguments here
write-host "script2.ps1"
write-host ($PSBoundParameters | ft * | out-string)
```

If you then call:

```
C:\> powershell .\script1.ps1 -Param1 "aaa" -Quiet:$true
```

you get this output:

```
script1.ps1

Key    Value
---    -----
Param1 aaa
Quiet  True

script2.ps1

Key    Value
---    -----
Param1 aaa
Quiet  True
```

and if you don't like the built-in `$PSBoundParameters` hashtable, you can build your own and splat that instead:

```
$mySplat = @{
    "Quiet" = $true
    "Param1" = "myParam1"
}
$mySplat.Add("Param2", "myParam2")
$mySplat.Remove("Quiet");
. .\script2.ps1 @mySplat
```